# How to display the products by brands

Tags: php, html, magento

I'm Using magento 1.7.0.2.
I used this code to display products by manufacturer.
but this shows that products by search criteria.

I need show the products products in individual page like [this page](http://www.poorvikamobile.com/index.php)(brands in left-bottom)

```
<?php 
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');  
    $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')  
    ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())  
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer');  
    $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());  
    $manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
?>


<h1>Brands</h1>

<ul id="manufacturer_list">  
    <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer): ?>  
        <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=<?php echo $manufacturer['value'] ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?></a></li>  
    <?php endforeach; ?>  
</ul>
```

some one help me.
thanx in advance.......  :)

Comment: can you pls elaborate whether you want products by manufacturer or manufacturers by product as in above code you are getting the latter.

Comment: *I need show the products products in individual page like **link***: Please do not link to external sources. The reason is that when a link gets obsolete, the question is no longer useful to future readers. We 

are trying to build a lasting repository of useful question/answer pairs here. Please read [can I just paste a link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the URL

```
<li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=<?php echo $manufacturer['value'] ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?></a></li>
```

To:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>NAMEOFTHECATEGORY?manufacturer=<?php echo $manufacturer['value'] ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?></a></li>
```

You should specify the NAMEOFTHECATEGORY of the products to display, otherwise it might not show all results. 
Otherwise you would need an extension like 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shop-by-brands.html or this one
http://amasty.com/improved-navigation.html which it's quite useful